# Using audio shortcode for .mp3 URLs with a query string

Tags: shortcode, audio, amazon

I'm trying to use the audio shortcode with an audio file with a query string on the end of the URL and it won't work. The reason is I'd like to use expiring signed URLs with Amazon S3.

If I use a URL like

> http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/audiofile.mp3

as the src in a call to `wp_audio_shortcode()` it works just fine. But if I use a URL like

> http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/audiofile.mp3?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXX&Expires=1234567890&Signature=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

then `wp_audio_shortcode()` just spits out an HTML link instead of the audio embed and player code. In my tests it appears the shortcode requires a file extension of .mp3 be at the end of the URL. Is there a way to make the short code work with a query string on the URL?

Any other solutions to suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem:

The problem seems to be that `wp_check_filetype()` doesn't recognize `mp3` files with `GET` parameters.

### Possible workarounds:

You have two options as far as I can see:

**1)** Override the audio shortcode with the `wp_audio_shortcode_override` filter.

**2)** or allow any audio extensions via the `wp_audio_extensions` filter.

Here's an example how you can implement the latter option:

```
/**
 * Allow unrecognize audio sources hosted on 'bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com'.
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/152352/26350
 */

add_filter( 'wp_audio_shortcode_override',
    function( $html, $atts )
    {
        if( 'bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com' === parse_url( $atts['src'], PHP_URL_HOST ) )
        {
            add_filter( 'wp_audio_extensions', 'wpse_152316_wp_audio_extensions' );
        }
        return $html;
    }
, PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
```

where

```
function wpse_152316_wp_audio_extensions( $ext )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    $ext[] = '';
    return $ext;
}
```

So just to explain what's happening here:

Right before the `wp_get_audio_extensions()` call, inside the `wp_audio_shortcode()`  function, we "hijack" the `wp_audio_shortcode_override` hook, to allow the empty audio file extension.
The reason for this is that the `wp_check_filetype()` check returns an empty string for unrecognized file extensions. We then make sure that this modification only applies when the audio source is hosted on `bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect! Option 2 works a treat. I had found the wp_audio_shortcode_override and suspected I could do something like that but was having trouble getting to your elegant solution.

Comment: @timeuser, glad to hear it worked for you. Hopefully audio files with GET parameters will be natively supported in the future.