# How can I get the [video] shortcode to allow query string parameters?

Tags: shortcode, videos, query-string, video-player

Using WordPress 4.4.2 (latest version as of writing this)

I'm trying to use the [video] shortcode to show a video on my site. If I provide a url ending with the `filename.mp4` it works fine:

`[video src="http://example.com/filename.mp4"]`

but when I add a querystring parameter to the end of the URL, it refuses to show the video player. Instead, it just shows me a link to the URL:

`[video src="http://example.com/filename.mp4?type=0"]`

I've tried using the `mp4` attribute, and it produces the same result.

How do I get the [video] shortcode to allow querystring parameters in the `src` or `mp4` attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got two options.

Either you filter your valid video extentions as @birgire recommended.

> I remember a similar issue for the audio shortcode [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152316/using-audio-shortcode-for-mp3-urls-with-a-query-string/).
>
> There I found a workaround by allowing the *empty* audio extension.
>
> You could try something similar with the video extensions. Here's a
>   demo plugin:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Allow the empty video extension to support GET parameters
>  */
> add_filter( 'wp_video_extensions', function( $ext )
> {
>     $ext[] = '';
>     return $ext;
> } );
> ```
>
> You should then restrict this further as needed, e.g. in a similar way
>   as I did with the audio shortcode.
>
> I searched the trac tickets and found this one [#30377](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30377) that's being
>   worked on.

Or filter the whole shortcode to your needs with the filter `wp_video_shortcode`. E.g. add another attribute to the shortcode called type and modify the result to your need.

```
function my_video_shortcode($output, $atts, $video, $post_id, $library ) {
    /**
     * @param string $output  Video shortcode HTML output.
     * @param array  $atts    Array of video shortcode attributes.
     * @param string $video   Video file.
     * @param int    $post_id Post ID.
     * @param string $library Media library used for the video shortcode.
     */
}
```

Source: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/media.php#L2369

Answer (score 2):

I remember a similar issue for the audio shortcode [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152316/using-audio-shortcode-for-mp3-urls-with-a-query-string/).

There I found a workaround by allowing the *empty* audio extension.

You could try something similar with the video extensions. Here's a demo plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:  GET Parameters In The Video Shortcode
 * Description:  Allow video files with GET parameters in the video shortcode [video]
 * Author:       Birgir Erlendsson (birgire)
 * Plugin URI:   https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/220573/26350
 * Version:      1.0.0
 */
add_filter( 'wp_video_shortcode_override', function( $html, $atts )
{
    add_filter( 'wp_video_extensions', 'wpse_video_extensions' );
    return $html;
}, 10, 2 );

function wpse_video_extensions( $ext )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    $ext[] = '';
    return $ext;
}
```

You should then restrict this further as needed, e.g. in a similar way as I did with the audio shortcode.

I searched the trac tickets and found this one [#30377](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30377) that's being worked on.